# it looks like source/target is not zero indexed networkd3

Tags: r, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I am trying to make an interactive website traffic diagram using web traffic data.

Using [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) packages.

It is just a `simpleNetwork`, however keeps giving me this warning and force closes RStudio.

```
library(networkD3)
simpleNetwork(data.frame(BWT2012$Visitors, 1:189157, fontSize = 16, nodeColour = "blue", nodeClickColour = "red", textColour = "black", opacity = 0.6, zoom = T))
```

> Warning Message: It looks like Source/Target is not zero-indexed. This
>   is required in Javascript and so your plot may not render.

I have been researching for hours however cannot seem to find how this works. I understand that javascript reads from 0 and r from 1. That is why it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. it is very difficult for anyone to help you because you haven't provided a reproducible example, i.e. we have no idea what your data frame `BWT2012` looks like
2. there seems to be a bug in your code... `data.frame(BWT2012$Visitors, 1:189157, fontSize = 16, nodeColour = "blue", nodeClickColour = "red", textColour = "black", opacity = 0.6, zoom = T)` will not work no matter what `BWT2012` looks like because you're passing elements to the `data.frame` function that are of different lengths. I suspect you meant for it to be `simpleNetwork(data.frame(BWT2012$Visitors, 1:189157), fontSize = 16, nodeColour = "blue", nodeClickColour = "red", textColour = "black", opacity = 0.6, zoom = T)`, where the first argument of the `simpleNetwork()` function is a complete `data.frame()` with `BWT2012$Visitors` as its first argument and `1:189157` as its second argument, i.e. you intend to pass to the `simpleNetwork()` function a data frame that has the first column/variable equal to `BWT2012$Visitors` and the second column equal to `1:189157`
3. Assuming #2 above is correct, the data frame you are trying to pass is telling `simpleNetwork` that the values in `BWT2012$Visitors` are the sources of each link, and the values in `1:189157` are the targets of each link. That seems like a very unlikely scenario, so I would make sure you're getting what you think you're getting.
4. The warning you mention is just a warning... it will not stop the function from running. In many (maybe all since recent changes in [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3)) cases it will still plot the graph, though the results might be unexpected. For instance...

   ```
   Source <- c(1, 1, 2)
   Target <- c(2, 3, 3)
   NetworkData <- data.frame(Source, Target)
   simpleNetwork(NetworkData)
   ```
5. Using the example from #4, if you wanted to renumber your source and target ids so that they were 0-indexed and avoid the warning, you could do...

   ```
   Source <- c(1, 1, 2)
   Target <- c(2, 3, 3)
   Source <- Source - 1
   Target <- Target - 1
   NetworkData <- data.frame(Source, Target)
   simpleNetwork(NetworkData)
   ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for commenting. The file I am working with is very large(with a massive 189157 lines). How can I possible upload or show this file to you?

Comment: `library(networkD3)
Source <- c(1, 1, 2)
Target <- c(2, 3, 3)
Source <- Source - 1
Target <- Target - 1
NetworkData <- data.frame(Source, Target)
simpleNetwork(NetworkData)
simpleNetwork(data.frame(BWT2012$Visitors, 1:189157), fontSize = 16, nodeColour = "blue", nodeClickColour = "red", textColour = "black", opacity = 0.6, zoom = T)`                                                                                                I have tried this with no luck. first time working with R.

Comment: Often you can reduce a large dataset to a smaller one, but still have the same effect to demonstrate the problem... so maybe only the first 5 rows of `BWT2012` would be sufficient to see the problem and/or replicate it. The code you pasted above, excluding the last line which you added in definitely works. Also, I can tell you before you bother struggling... trying to plot 200,000 links with networkD3 is not going to go well... it's simply not designed to handle that many links.

Comment: also see here for tips on how to good reproducible examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example